# How to change name of Radio button dynamically in android studio?

Tags: java, android, dynamic, radio-button, radio-group

I am dynamically creating radio buttons as per the count given in the edit text.
I want to edit the name of the radiobutton after it gets created dynamically in the app, like the user has the privilege to name the radio button in the app.
How should I do that android studio
This is my code for creating dyanmic radiobuttons so far.
**Here in the code rbn.setText("Radiobutton"+i) names the radiobutton as Radiobutton1, Radiobutton2, etc. instead of that I want to change the name of that in the app dynamically and write the name of the radiobutton one by one, help would appreciated please!**

````
package com.example.EZPoll;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

public class Public_create extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText mEtNumOfRadioBtns;
    Button mBtnAdd;
    RadioGroup mRgAllButtons;
    String option_name;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_public_create);
        mEtNumOfRadioBtns = findViewById(R.id.et_no);
        mBtnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        mRgAllButtons = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
        mBtnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int number=Integer.parseInt(mEtNumOfRadioBtns.getText().toString().trim());
                for (int i = 1; i <= number ; i++) {
                    RadioButton rbn = new RadioButton(Public_create.this);
                    rbn.setId(View.generateViewId());
                    rbn.setText("Radiobutton "+i);
                    mRgAllButtons.addView(rbn);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to rephrase your question a bit to make it more clear. Where is the user going to input the names of the buttons, what have you tried to facilitate that so far, etc!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you have now is that you can't reference the buttons created in the loop through user interaction. I suggest creating a `List<myData>` which contains a `RadioButton` and an `EditText`, show them in a `RecyclerView` or `ListView`.

Then the user can edit the name of the `RadioButton` throught the `EditText` one by one.

Comment: hello, thank you for your quick response, can you help with the code to what you said?

Comment: No, you have to code it by yourself, remember: "The community is here to help you with specific coding, algorithm, or language problems." not to do all your coding.